# Remove Duplicates while retaining order, Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
removeDup([],[]).
removeDup([H|T],T1) :- member(H,T), removeDup(T,T1).
removeDup([H|T],T1) :- not(member(H,T)), removeDup(T,Q), append(T1,[H],Q).
```

This removes the duplicates but changes the order. For append I'm expecting H to be added to the end of T1, then set as Q.

How can i retain the order?

Intended behaviour:

```
?- removeDup([1,2,3,2,4,5],X).
X = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: there is something wrong with your third clause. Are you sure that is the program you use?

Answer (score 1):

```
rmdup(Xs, Ys) :- rmdup1(Xs, Ys, []).
```

Here `Zs` is the accumulator for non duplicate elements of the list. If `X` is in `Zs`, ignore it, else push it on the list.

```
rmdup1([], Ys, Zs) :- reverse(Ys, Zs).
rmdup1([X|Xs], Ys, Zs) :-
    member(X, Zs) -> rmdup1(Xs, Ys, Zs); 
    rmdup1(Xs, Ys, [X|Zs]).
```

Comment: Try `listing(rmdup1)` to see a better indentation style for if-then-else

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
dedupe( Xs, Set ) :- dedupe_1(Xs, [], Set).

dedupe_1( []     , _    , []  ).
dedupe_1( [X|Xs] , Seen , Set ) :-
  ( member(X, Seen)
    ->    Set1  = Set
    ;  [X|Set1] = Set
  ),
  dedupe_1( Xs, [X|Seen], Set1 ).
```

The drawback is that it costs you in terms of space used. You can avoid that at the expense of a `reverse/2` at the end:

```
dedupe(Xs, Set) :- dedupe_1(Xs, [], Set).

dedupe_1( []     , Seen , Set ) :- reverse( Seen, Set).
dedupe_1( [X|Xs] , Seen , Set ) :-
  ( member(X,Seen)
    ->    Acc1  = Acc
    ;  [X|Acc1] = Acc
  ),
  dedupe_1( Xs, Acc1, Set).
```